How Can I Access Online Meeting Details for All Users in My Organization Using Microsoft Graph API?
I'm trying to access online meeting details and transcript for any user in my organization using the Microsoft Graph API. My goal is to allow a single application to read online meeting data across all users in the company without needing to specify individual users.
What I’ve Tried:
Application Permissions:

I granted my application the following permissions in Azure AD:

OnlineMeetings.Read.All

OnlineMeetingTranscript.Read.All

Other related permissions like User.Read.All, Group.Read.All.



I expected that with these permissions, my app could access meeting
details for any user in the organization.


Issue: When I try to access a meeting or its transcript with the following API call::
https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users/{user-id}/onlineMeetings/{meeting-id}

https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users/{user-id}/onlineMeetings/{meeting-id}/transcripts/{transcript-id}/content

I receive the error:
{
    "error": {
        "code": "General",
        "message": "No application access policy found for this app.",
        "innerError": {
            "request-id": "xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx",
            "date": "2024-08-13T19:47:25",
            "client-request-id": "xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx"
        }
    }
}

My Goal:
I want my application to access online meeting details for any user in the organization without having to manually assign an access policy to each user or group. Ideally, I want a solution where my application can read meeting details company-wide.
Questions:

Is there a way to bypass the need for an Application Access Policy
when using OnlineMeetings.Read.All and OnlineMeetingTranscript.Read.All so that my app can access
meetings    across the entire organization?
If an access policy is mandatory, is there a more scalable approach
to apply it company-wide without manually assigning it to every user
or group?
Are there alternative methods or best practices for achieving
company-wide access to online meetings using Microsoft Graph API?


Any update on the issue?

Created a Microsoft Entra ID application and granted application type API permissions same as you:

Generated access token:
https://login.microsoftonline.com/TenantID/oauth2/v2.0/token

client_id:ClientID
client_secret:ClientSecret
scope↵:https://graph.microsoft.com/.default
grant_type:client_credentials


When I tried to access a meeting, I got the same error:
https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users/{user-id}/onlineMeetings/{meeting-id}


The error usually occurs if application access policy is not created and granted.
To resolve the error, create an Application Access Policy like below:
 Connect-MicrosoftTeams

New-CsApplicationAccessPolicy -Identity Rukkpolicy -AppIds "AppID" -Description "RukkPolicy"


To grant the policy where the application can read meeting details company-wide/to access all users under the tenant use the flag -Global:

Now I am able to access meetings for any user under the tenant successfully:
https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users/{user-id}/onlineMeetings/{meeting-id}


Reference:
Grant-CsApplicationAccessPolicy (MicrosoftTeamsPowerShell) | Microsoft
